# Задача с ProgressBar-ом в ListView

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

В игре 4 списка с выборами действий персонажа. При нажатии на каждый айтем каждого списка выполняется действие. Чтобы повторить выполнение действия еще раз, нужно подождать (время ожидания везде разное, назовем его таймаут); При нажатии на айтем на его заднем фоне начинает действовать горизонтальный прогрессбар. Когда прогрессбар дойдет до конца действие можно повторить. От времени таймаута зависит скорость прогрессирования.

Вообщем, я вешаю слушатель на список...

```
lv_inspiration.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int p3, long p4)
    {
    b = (ProgressBar)p2.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_item);
    cdt = new CountDownTimer(100000,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        i++;
        b.setProgress(i);
    }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        i=0;
        }
        };
        cdt.start();
    }
});
```

И получаю такую картину - при нажатии на айтем запускается прогрессбар и начинает работу. Если мне дождаться, когда он закончит и нажать на второй, то ничего не происходит. Если нажать на второй во время выполнения первого, то первый останавливается, второй продолжает прогресс с точки остановки первого и причем с удвоенной скоростью. К тому же, при прокрутке слетают прогрессы. Что не так? Помогите, может есть какая нибудь статья? Или может кто видел такую реализацию где-то?

**UPD**
 Изменил код метода `getView()` в своем `SimpleAdapter`, теперь другие айтемы отоично работают, когда в одном прогрессбар доходит до конца. Но, если кликнуть на айтем и прокрутить список, чтобы нажатый айтем не было видно, то прогрессбар продолжает работу в других айтемах, то есть "перескакивает". А если не дожидаясь  конца первого нажать на второй, то первый останавливается, второй продолжает прогресс с удвоенной скоростью. Ну, и так далее с этим эффект. Помогите, что не так? И что за чертовщина с этим ListView?

Comment: То есть получается, что прогресс бар переключается в своем выполнении на новый айтем? Как прогресс бар получает новый прогресс?

Comment: @Ivan Vovk, да)) переключается на нажатый) я не знаю как заставлять список держать все прогрессбары в айтемах :( и чтобы ничего никуда не переходило, и чтобы все прогрессбары работали независимо друг от друга. Прогрессбар получает прогресс через CountDownTimer. Код в вопросе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте отдельный класс для прогресс бара и сделайте его неотменяемым:

```
public class Helper {
ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

// Пользователь ожидает окончания загрузки данных
public void showProgress(Context context,String text) {
    if (progressDialog == null) {
        try {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", text);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
public void hideProgress() {
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        progressDialog = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Теперь начало и конец прогресс бара зависят от вашей логики. Запускайте выполнение айтема и сразу прогресс бара, как айтем отработает вырубайте прогресс бар.

Comment: @Herrgott, всмысле инициализировать заранее?)

Comment: @Сергей Вы что-то определенно напутали здесь в комментариях :)

Comment: @Herrgott, вы о чем? :)

Comment: @сергей мой вопрос ниже, а спрашиваете меня в этом, а моём спрашиваете других

Answer (score 0):

создайте `CountDownTimer` вне слушателя и проверяйте, если он запущен ничего не делать, если не запущен запускаем с параметрами таймаута и пр.

И лучше инициализировать `View` заранее, я про `b = (ProgressBar)p2.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_item);` внутри слушателя